# Galaxy s4 charges but cannot be detected as usb device

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, usb-connection-mode

When i connect the phone neither phone alerts it is connected nor pc recognizes as usb device.
On linux when i try `lsblk` command i cannot see the phone either .
This is not a linux specific problem under windows i have the same problem except charging cannot do anything via usb how can i solve this issue.
Android version 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

In Settings or from the notification area, there should be a setting when connected via USB, is that set to "Charging Only"?  If so, set it to MTP/Mass Storage Mode instead.  I can't remember how Samsung words it.

Comment: phone doesn't detect connection as well